# Contraction and extension of ideals respect inclusions, sums and intersections

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, localization

Let $R$ be an integral domain.
Let $Y$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of $R$ which contains $1$ but not $0$.

Define $S=RY^{-1}=\lbrace ry^{-1} : r \in R, y \in Y \rbrace$ as well as $\mathcal{I}(R)$ and $\mathcal{I}(S)$ to be the sets of ideals of $R$ and $S$ respectively.

The maps $c:\mathcal{I}(S) \to \mathcal{I}(R)$ and $e:\mathcal{I}(R) \to \mathcal{I}(S)$ are given by $c(J)=J \cap R$ and $e(I)=IS$.

> I'm trying to show that these maps respect inclusions, intersections and sums.

I'm confused about the non-trivial ones, i.e. sums for both maps and also intersections in the case of $e$. I feel like this is all very much just about notations and manipulation but I can't get my head around it. Can anyone give me a hand?

**EDIT**: manipulations give $(I+J)Y^{-1}=IY^{-1}+JY^{-1}$ for any two ideals $I$ and $J$ of $R$ so $(I+J)S=(I+J)RY^{-1}=IRY^{-1}+JRY^{-1}=IS+JS$  so $e$ respects sums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $S^{-1}I\cap S^{-1}J\subseteq S^{-1}(I\cap J)$, let $x\in S^{-1}I\cap S^{-1}J$. Then $x=\frac as=\frac bt$ with $a\in I$ and $b\in J$. Then there is $u\in S$ such that $uta=usb\in I\cap J$. Now write $x=\frac{uta}{uts}\in S^{-1}(I\cap J)$.

Let $R=K[X,Y]$, $f=X+Y$, $S=\{1,f,f^2,\dots\}$, $I=(X)$, and $J=(Y)$. Then $S^{-1}I\cap R=I$ and $S^{-1}J\cap R=J$ (since $I,J$ are prime ideals and $I\cap S=J\cap S=\emptyset$), while $(S^{-1}I+S^{-1}J)\cap R=S^{-1}(I+J)\cap R=S^{-1}R\cap R=R$ (since $(I+J)\cap S\ne\emptyset$).

Comment: I totally see this now, I was trying to write sums which complicated it a lot... If I find the last case, I'll close the question, thank you for your quick reaction to this!

Comment: I'm not following the first two equalities and the very last one (in the counterexample I mean)... Sorry, I'm being very slow about this... Also, isn't it a problem for contractions not to respect sums?

Comment: @Kika Yes, it's about the contractions, and I've chosen the ideals of $S^{-1}R$ of the form $S^{-1}I$ and $S^{-1}J$ (in fact, all ideals of $S^{-1}R$ are of this form), I've summed them up, and then I've contracted them. On one side I get $I+J$ (the sum of contractions), and on the other side I get $R$ (the contraction of the sum).

Comment: Don't we actually have $R=I+J$ ?

Comment: @Kika I don't think that $(X)+(Y)=K[X,Y]$. (You can show that $1\notin(X,Y)$.)

Comment: You're right, $K$ isn't in $(X) +(Y)$. I'm very confused because the maps are mutual inverses so one respecting sums and not the other sounds unintuitive...

Comment: @Kika I also don't think "*the maps are mutual inverses*": in general, $I^{ec}\ne I$ and $J^{ce}\ne J$.

Comment: This is my bad again, they are mutual inverses only if we consider ideals of R that are contractions of ideals in the bigger set, but it still makes it a bit counterintuitive to me...